# Flex 4 stopping an embbeded SWF

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have this Flex 4.1 script:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Embed(source="res/swf/user.swf")]
        [Bindable]
        private var SWFClass:Class; 

        [Bindable]
        public var userClip:MovieClip = new SWFClass();

        protected function test_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace("click");
            userClip.gotoAndPlay(1);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<mx:SWFLoader id="userClip1" autoLoad="true"  trustContent="true" source="{userClip}"  />
<mx:Button id="test" click="test_clickHandler(event)" x="100" y="200"/>
```

I only see the SWF repeating itself, pressing the button has no effect, no errors either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `trace(userClip);` print?

Comment: ChelseaQuizFlex.ApplicationSkin3._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.userClip1 that's the only thing...

FYI it does show me the SWF, I just can't do anything with it.

Comment: Does SWFClass call super() in its constructor?

Comment: No why would it? This is the complete code (except for a header).
This is Flex 4 not Flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [unloadAndStop()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html?allClasses=1#unloadAndStop()).